# Possible Shared Library conflict causing corrupted SQLite database

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

Our app is a browser plugin for FF & Chrome. The app uses SQLite to store data. The SQLite files are getting corrupted on FF/Linux or FF/Mac.

Our *hypothesis* for the files etting corrupted is described below:

1) FF is loading SQLite 3.7.1 as a shared library
2) Our plugin (which is a shared library) is statically linked against
SQLite 3.7.4. We have made sure that our plugin is exporting only one
symbol NSGetModule (required by FF to load a plugin). All other
symbols are hidden using --version-script compiler option
3) Something *bad* is happening because of possible symbols conflicts
across multiple versions of SQLite library

Additional comments:

1) The same problem does not arise in Chrome as Chrome runs plugin in
separate processes
2) We are not facing this issue on Windows. Only on Linux or Mac
3) We have to use SQLite 3.7.4 as we are using the features of the latest version

Any ideas?

Comment: I can only think of two things. 1) Your hypothesis is wrong. 2) Check the output of "nm -s" to ensure not just what your plugin is exporting but also what it is externally referencing at load and confirm SQLite symbols are all resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess of the cause -- unexpected symbol conflict -- is quite likely correct.

If you have correctly hidden everything (as you say you did), then output from

```
nm -D your-plugin.so
```

on Linux should list only the `NSGetModule` as defined, and no `SQLite` symbols at all (I expect you'll still see quite a lot of unresolved symbols from `libc`, and whatever else you link your plugin against).

You can run Firefox on Linux with `LD_DEBUG=symbols,bindings`. That will produce many MBytes of output, but you should see very few references to your plugin, none for any `SQLite` symbols.

Is that what you *in fact* observe?